# Rails 3 error message - No route matches 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Below is a path, the relevant portion of my routes file, the relevant portion of rake routes result, and the error message. To further analyze the error i switched from ":only => " to using ":except => " and listed items one by one. ":except => :create" is the one that causes the error. I would prefer to use :only because its shorter. So why does ":create" cause the error? Is it possible that this is somehow related to the fact that one of the routes is ":create_invitation"? Thanks!

**path:**

```
<%= button_to "Finished", userhome_index_path %>
```

**routes:**

```
  resources :userhome, :only => :index do
    collection do
      post :create_invitation
    end
    member do
      get :edit_profile_picture
      post :update_profile_picture
    end
  end
```

**rake routes:**

```
userhome_index GET    /userhome(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"userhome"}
```

**error msg:**

```
No route matches "/userhome"
```

Comment: @NikitaBarsukov, @codinguser, @zetetic, and @SimoneCarletti. I was using ruby-on-rails-3 and routes tags to see if there was any other question like mine on SO and noticed that you all have answered route questions well. I have never asked someone i haven't interacted with already to look at a question and don't know if this is considered appropriate on SO. If you do answer i promise i won't bug you with a bunch of requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The button_to uses a POST request. You want a GET request.

```
<%= button_to "Finished", userhome_index_path, :method => :get %>
```

Comment: thanks for giving it a shot but i still get the same error. Did you see the UPDATE at the bottom?